# Angular Material related Hover issue in IE11

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, internet-explorer-11

I am working on displaying certain details on a card upon hovering over the top portion of the card using AngularJS, Angular Material and CSS.

This is the code pen created- https://codepen.io/SSPai/pen/oyVmZg

```
<md-button  md-no-ink  class="member-card" ng-click="">
            <div layout="column" layout-align="center center">
                <!-- The details should be shown upon hovering over "top-card-container" only -->
                 <div class="top-card-container">
                        <div class="member-photo-background mem-image"><md-icon class="member-photo">account_circle</md-icon></div>
                            <div class="member-details-part">
                                                    <div  layout="column" layout-align="space-around stretch">
                                                            <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center" class="member-details member-details-start">
                                                                <md-icon class="member-detail-info member-detail-icon">location_on</md-icon>
                              <div flex
                                   class="member-card-data member-detail-info  member-details-value member-title">
                                <div 
                                     ng-bind="memberLocation"></div>
                                <md-tooltip md-direction="right"
                                            ng-if="memberLocation">
                                  {{memberLocation}}
                                </md-tooltip>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           <div class="member-name-bar" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                  <div class=" member-card-data member-name">
                    <div 
                         ng-bind="memberDisplayName">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Even this display of tooltip in IE is not working-->
                    <md-tooltip>{{memberDisplayName}}</md-tooltip>
                  </div>

                </div>
        </div>
      </md-button>
```

The issue is that the above codepen **works perfectly in Chrome but not in IE11.** In IE11, upon hovering, the default hover property of the button is applied which is not desirable.

**In IE11:** The details upon hovering are not shown and the Tooltip upon hovering over the name in bottom portion of the card is not shown.

Please help in making the above code pen IE11 compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CSS rules for `.md-button` are interfering with your custom rules for hover effect. I would suggest to use a `<div>` tag for container instead of `<md-button>`.

Comment: Yes! The .md-button rules were interfering. Tried with div tag, worked fine in IE. Thank you.